# BigQuery datatypes

Tags: google-bigquery

I am starting with a new project and just wanted to verify before defining the table schema

Does BigQuery support anything other than:

```
string – 
integer –
float– 
boolean –
```

Comment: You can find the complete list of datatypes here, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

BigQuery data types official docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

---

The previous answer lists the basic datatypes:

- STRING
- INTEGER (INT64)
- FLOAT (FLOAT64)
- BOOLEAN

BigQuery also supports:

- RECORD (JSON objects, see nested records)
- TIMESTAMP
- BYTES
- DATE
- TIME
- DATETIME
- ARRAY
- STRUCT

2018 and now also:

- NUMERIC
- GEOGRAPHY

---

More on:

- Nested records: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested
- Using timestamp: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/timestamp
- Docs: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes

Comment: TIMESTAMP is not a string.  (On bigquery.cloud.google.com tables it does get printed out in string format, though)

Comment: @felipe-hoffa any chance BQ will support a native 'map' type?  Would be a great addition.  Was looking at Spark -> BQ type mappings (spark has Structs, Arrays and Maps natively)......can work around it of course, just wondering if it would be a native type at some point?

Comment: i think you also wanted to add link for standard SQL - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed.

```
BigQuery Type   ICD Type    Length    Checks

INTEGER         Integer     
FLOAT           Decimal     
STRING          Text        <65536  
BOOLEAN         Choice                "true" or "false", case-insensitive
```

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestionbestpractices#cutplace

Comment: Thanks Charles, just wanted to double check before defining the schema.
I was just hoping there was a data type for date time which I dint know of. :)

Comment: Not yet... I heard that this datetime type is on the way!

Answer (score 1):

Boolean also support 1 for true and 0 for false and Timestamp supports UTC or "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSSS"