# Google BigQuery Date Data Type?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a date or datetime data type in Google BigQuery?  I looked at the online documentation, but the data types mentioned didn't include any date types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2013 update:

BigQuery now has a Timestamp type.

Look at: [BigQuery datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722274/bigquery-datatypes/15754131#15754131)

2018: TIMESTAMP, TIME, DATE, DATETIME

Answer (score 2):

2016 update:

BigQuery now also has real DATE type (in addition to TIMESTAMP type) in standard SQL:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types#date-type
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#date

Answer (score -1):

Edited to add: There is a date time type, see Fh's answer for more information.

No date data type is available, although if you use ISO-formatted date-times (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.uuuuuu]) or timestamps (convertable to microseconds since 1970) there are a number of date functions that you can use. See [this](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#timestampfunctions) page for more information.