# bigquery: Loading "DATE", "INT64" and "FLOAT64" types not supported?

Tags: google-bigquery

According to [Google BigQuery Date Data Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219885/google-bigquery-date-data-type), bigquery **standard SQL** now has a real DATE data type. However, trying to load a table fails with:

```
$ bq load -F'|' --ignore_unknown_values test.table1 source.csv name:string,mydate:date
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r385016d9cc84259d_0000015511b08bfc_1 ... (2s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'test-1320:bqjob_r385016d9cc84259d_0000015511b08bfc_1': An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed
```

Also it looks like the standard SQL-advertised data types INT64 and FLOAT64 in schemas aren't supported either:

```
$ bq load -F'|' --ignore_unknown_values test.table1 source2.csv key:INT64,desc:string
BigQuery error in load operation: Invalid value for: INT64 is not a valid value
```

Is that expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATE` is still rolling out through our stack. Support for using this type in load jobs was checked in yesterday and will hopefully be out in production next week.

`FLOAT64` and `INT64` are currently understood only in the standard SQL query language. For load jobs, please continue to use `FLOAT` and `INTEGER` for now (they're equivalent to the `64` versions in standard SQL).

Comment: Thanks, will wait and test the DATE type.

Comment: Seems to be working now, I was just able to do a load of a table with a DATE column. Thanks!

Comment: btw, FYI, it seems to be intermittent, some loads work, some don't but eventually do if you retry enough times.

Comment: We have a multi-day rollout process, so you're probably hitting a mix of new servers and old servers. Assuming there's no rollback, it should work 100% of the time in a few days.

Comment: Queries using DATE columns, on the other hand, seem to be failing 100% of the time.

Comment: I'm running a query as simple as: SELECT desc FROM test.sampletable WHERE mydate <= DATE_ADD("1998-12-01", INTERVAL -90 DAY); or, equally simple: SELECT desc FROM test.sampletable WHERE mydate < '1995-03-15';

Comment: I'm guessing you filed https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=565? Per that link, bug confirmed and fix incoming. It may take a little while for the fix to hit prod depending on where it is in the stack, but there's a workaround provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use respective flag to [enable standard sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false